# chinese tokenizer stanford core nlp

Tags: nlp, tokenize, stanford-nlp

Can somebody help me use the stanford core nlp to tokenize chinese text in java.
This is my code so far:

```
File file = new File("example.txt");
   file.createNewFile();
   FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
   fileWriter.write("这是很好");
   fileWriter.flush();
   fileWriter.close();
   FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);

   InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"UTF-8");

   CHTBTokenizer chineseTokenizer = new CHTBTokenizer(isReader);

   String nextToken = "";
   while((nextToken = chineseTokenizer.getNext())!=null)
       System.out.println(nextToken);
```

But instead of getting 3 seperate tokens I'm getting the whole sentence as a single token.
Can somebody help me out?

Comment: According to http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/international/pennchinese/CHTBTokenizer.html, `CHTBTokenizer` looks more like a tokenizer for some special file format, not for plain Chinese text?

Comment: Apparently the word segmenter is not a part of the CoreNLP package yet for some reason... One can directly download it from its own separate page.

Answer (score 1):

The `CHTBTokenizer` is used to tokenize constituency trees in PTB format.

For plain Chinese text you have to use a segmenter which is also available from Stanford. You can find more information and a download link on the [Stanford Word Segmenter](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/segmenter.shtml) page.